does exist a way to redirect sound to car without use the media category for car app?
I’m currently using the Messaging category in my Android Auto app to display records (they’re not actual chat messages) that include text and some audio resources. To play the audio, I use the MediaPlayer class from android.media.MediaPlayer
However, I’m encountering an issue: the audio resource only plays on my phone and only if the app is in the foreground (I need play it in my car). I’m wondering if it’s feasible to continue with this approach, or if it would be better to switch to the Media category and use the MediaBrowserServiceCompat API to handle audio playback more effectively within the Android Auto environment.
What would you recommend?
